# A Windows 8 computer for exactly two applications

Tags: windows-8

How would you configure Windows 8 so that there were exactly two tiles on the start screen: one for QuickBooks, and one for a Word document named "To Do" ?

Comment: Haven't looked into it in detail, but if you upgrade to Windows 8.1, there should be such a thing as a "booth mode", something like that, that allows you to "lock" the device for a precise use. Look it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unpin all other items from the start screen.  I apologize for the short answer, perhaps there is more to your question.  Unpin everything you don't want from the start screen, and make sure those 2 are the only items pinned to the start screen.